# Unable to create custom image for dataproc

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to create custom image for my dataproc cluster as per this document https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/guides/dataproc-images. However, it is throwing this error. could you please help ?

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "generate_custom_image.py",
>   line 419, in 
>       run()   File "generate_custom_image.py", line 360, in run
>       dataproc_base_image = get_dataproc_base_image(args.dataproc_version)   File
>   "generate_custom_image.py", line 98, in get_dataproc_base_image
>       if stdout and isinstance(stdout, basestring): NameError: name 'basestring' is not defined

Comment: As an immediate workaround, Python 2.7 can be used to run this script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've filed https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-dataproc/issues/50 to support Python 3. In the meantime, Python 2.7 is required to create custom images.